QGIS Identify multiple intersecting vectors
I have 30+ vectors layers (constraints to tree planting). I want to be able to draw a polygon vector and be able to identify which of the 30 constraints are present within this 'planting' polygon.
The 'identify tool' does half a job, but I would like to move towards identifying the constraints, then automating a report generated.

The spatial join tool will transfer the attributes of your tree planting constraints to the attribute table of your polygons if and only if those vectors overlap.  Here is a tutorial on spatial joining.

I've created a model with two input parameter:

Multiple input. Which allows you to select the 30+ vector layers
Vector layer, for your drawn layer


The model merges all 30+ layer into one (they all have to be the same type. If you have point, line and polygon layer your can buffer the points and lines by a small distance to convert them to polygons).
The merge output will have a column named layer, with the layer name.
It then intersects the merge with the drawing layer to create:

